# Intellij and Pycharm annotate showing a fixed wrong date

Tags: java, git, intellij-idea, pycharm, git-blame

I am facing a quite bizarre situation regarding Intellij IDEA and Pycharm annotate (git blame) functionality.

Late last year I decided to install different JDKs on my MacOS Mojave (version 10.14.6) for development purposes. It seemingly messed up things quite bit, so I spent some time trying to  "undo" (i.e., removing) the JDKs and jEnv. I am able to start and use IntelliJ IDEA and PyCharm (in fact, I never lost the ability to start and use them), but both programs now show a wrong fixed date (10/01/2019) for all the lines when I click on "Annotate" option of every versioned file no matter how old or new is the line. If I use git blame on the command line I see the correct dates of each file's lines. Downloading and installing the newest version of Intellij IDEA didn't help to solve the issue. Please, anyone could help me restore the default behaviour?

The default java version is below:
openjdk version "11.0.1" 2018-10-16
OpenJDK Runtime Environment 18.9 (build 11.0.1+13)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM 18.9 (build 11.0.1+13, mixed mode)

1. git blame on CLI:
   [image]
2. Annotate option in Intellij IDEA:
   [image]

The default java version is:
openjdk version "11.0.1" 2018-10-16
OpenJDK Runtime Environment 18.9 (build 11.0.1+13)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM 18.9 (build 11.0.1+13, mixed mode)

The git version is:
git version 2.21.1 (Apple Git-122.3)

The Intellij IDEA and PyCharm versions are:

IntelliJ IDEA 2020.3.1 (Community Edition)
Build #IC-203.6682.168, built on December 29, 2020
Runtime version: 11.0.9.1+11-b1145.63 x86_64
VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM by JetBrains s.r.o.
macOS 10.14.6
GC: ParNew, ConcurrentMarkSweep
Memory: 990M
Cores: 4
Registry: editor.distraction.free.mode=true
Non-Bundled Plugins: DBN

PyCharm 2019.3.4 (Community Edition)
Build #PC-193.6911.25, built on March 18, 2020
Runtime version: 11.0.6+8-b520.43 x86_64
VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM by JetBrains s.r.o
macOS 10.14.6
GC: ParNew, ConcurrentMarkSweep
Memory: 990M
Cores: 4
Registry:
Non-Bundled Plugins: com.alayouni.ansiHighlight, com.intellij.ideolog

Answer (score 0):

Try to right click on the annotations in Intellij -> Options -> Show Commit Timestamp.

Comment: I tried after your post, but it didn't solve the issue. :(